# Command to use with easy way the insert of R dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe loaded successfully in `R`.

I would like to give the data of df to someone else to use them with quick and easy way without need to load again the file into a df.

Which is the command to give the whole data of df (not the str())

Comment: dput(df) which outputs the dataframe.  Copy the data and send it to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the file into a `.RData` using `save` or `save.image`, depending on your needs. First one will save specific objects while the latter will dump the whole workspace to a file. This method has the advantage of working on probably any R object.

Another option is as @user1945827 mentioned, using `dput` which will produce a string that is parseable into another R session. This will not work for complex (like S4) objects.